# Android Studio 3.0 RC 2

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> Failed to execute aapt

        2017-10-24 08:17:11,957 [se-915-b01]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor: 1.0 
        2017-10-24 08:17:45,060 [entQueue-0]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
        2017-10-24 08:17:53,301 [entQueue-0]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 37 plugins initialized in 21652 ms 
        2017-10-24 08:17:53,310 [entQueue-0]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android APK Support (1.0), Android Games (1.0), Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.3.0 RC 2), App Links Assistant (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (171.4249.39), EditorConfig (171.4249.39), Firebase App Indexing (0.1), Firebase Services (0.1), Firebase Testing (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (171.4249.39), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Developers Samples (0.3.1), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle (171.4249.39), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (171.4249.39), IDEA CORE (171.4249.39), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (171.4249.39), Kotlin (1.1.51-release-Studio3.0-1), Properties Support (171.4249.39), Settings Repository (171.4249.39), Smali Support (1.0), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), Test Recorder (1.0), TestNG-J (8.0), YAML (171.4249.39), hg4idea (10.0) 
        2017-10-24 08:18:40,634 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted: corruption marker found 
        2017-10-24 08:18:40,790 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Filesystem storage is corrupted or does not exist. [Re]Building. Reason: Corruption marker file found 
        2017-10-24 08:18:41,094 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted: 'C:\Users\tigani\.AndroidStudio3.0\system\caches\names.dat' does not exist 
        2017-10-24 08:18:41,168 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=4042 
        2017-10-24 08:18:41,910 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
        2017-10-24 08:18:42,275 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
        2017-10-24 08:19:06,227 [se-915-b01]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - FS has been rebuild, rebuilding local history... 
        2017-10-24 08:19:13,342 [se-915-b01]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
        2017-10-24 08:19:17,667 [d thread 1]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
        2017-10-24 08:19:17,770 [se-915-b01]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
        2017-10-24 08:19:28,307 [se-915-b01]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:8404 
        2017-10-24 08:19:28,323 [se-915-b01]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:15 
        2017-10-24 08:19:28,997 [se-915-b01]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:585 
        2017-10-24 08:19:28,998 [se-915-b01]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:1 
        2017-10-24 08:19:30,922 [se-915-b01]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
        2017-10-24 08:19:47,029 [d thread 3]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - Name storage is repaired 
        2017-10-24 08:19:57,799 [se-915-b01]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 19 project components initialized in 16498 ms 
        2017-10-24 08:20:00,583 [d thread 3]   INFO - ij.psi.stubs.StubUpdatingIndex - Following new file types will be indexed:Groovy,XML,HTML,LLDBCommands,kotlin_builtins,Properties,KJSM,GDBCommands,CLASS,JAVA,Kotlin 
        2017-10-24 08:20:16,391 [d thread 3]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:48065 
        2017-10-24 08:20:23,363 [d thread 3]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:6972 
        2017-10-24 08:20:51,037 [se-915-b01]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 87 application components initialized in 199394ms 
        2017-10-24 08:20:51,380 [se-915-b01]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 255295 ms 
        2017-10-24 08:21:01,364 [d thread 1]   INFO - atibilityChecksMetadataUpdater - Failed to parse XML metadata 
        org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
            at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
            at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
            at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:287)
            at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:306)
            at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.compatibility.CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.lambda$null$1(CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.java:85)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:420)
            at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:420)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:395)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:61)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:263)
            at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.compatibility.CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.lambda$fetchMetadata$2(CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.java:83)
            at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
            at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanExternalID(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
            ... 17 more
        Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
            at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanExternalID(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
            at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
            at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:287)
            at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:306)
            at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.compatibility.CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.lambda$null$1(CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.java:85)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:420)
            at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:420)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:395)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:61)
            at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:263)
            at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.compatibility.CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.lambda$fetchMetadata$2(CompatibilityChecksMetadataUpdater.java:83)
            at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at `enter code here`java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you post the log

Comment: I posted @Fakher

Comment: I had the same error recently and I would suggest you to check your resources as the error could be there. One solution is to create an empty working project and paste there all your resources and check one by one which is related with dependencies and what errors the AS will show.  Problem in my case was that AS doesnt show you where the problem is exactly with your code. While doing changes the error was changing until it showed the right one

Comment: thanks im trying several hours to solve the problem @Ultimo_m

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add the following code to the file "**gradle.properties**" in your project.

```
    android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: If we use this code working.But not able to get the apk in build ->output folder.Its stopping the output file

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this very issue today morning and found the solution for it too. This issue is created when you have messed up one of your **.xml** files. I'll suggest you to go through them one by one and look for recent changes made. It might be caused a silly mistake.

In my case, I accidentally hardcoded a color string as #FFFFF (Bad practice, I know. I was just trying out variations). As you can see it had 5 F instead on 6. It didn't show any warning but was root of the same issue as encountered by you