# Android Project Build failure: error: failed to create directory 'C:\tmp\MyApplication'

Tags: android, android-studio, build, tmp

I am trying to build-run an Android project, downloaded from Github. My PC has two drives; the first *one* (C:) has the android studio and windows installed and the *other* (D:) is used for storage. The problem appears **ONLY** if the project is located in the secondary drive (D:); on my main one it works with no problems. The log is the following :

```
Error:failed to create directory 'C:\tmp\MyApplication\CreateLayout\app\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\android\branch1'.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Failed to execute aapt
```

It's the only project, that I have seen, that needs a /tmp folder to be created. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910532/android-studio-3-0-rc-2/46947538#46947538

Answer (score 1):

You can use a symbolic link to put all dirs on the same drive. That is the way I do it. I have my source code on D: and build folder on T: then I just create 2 symbolic link's folders on C: pointing to those folders. To the IDE it all seems coming from C: and so, no errors.

Here is how to make them in case you don't know:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink